# Dictionary sized change due to iteration of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to remove key-value pairs from a dict when a sub-dictionary matches values from another dictionary.

Example set-up:

```
e = {'a':{'aa':'yes'}, 'b':{'ac':'no'}, 'a':{'aa':'yes'}}
f = {'a':{'aa':'yes'}, 'e':{'ab':'no'}, 'a':{'aa':'yes'}}

for keys, values in e.items():
    for k, v in f.items():
        if values.get('aa') == v.get('aa'):
            e.pop(keys)
```

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Expected result:

```
#from
e = {'a':{'aa':'yes'}, 'b':{'ac':'no'}, 'a':{'aa':'yes'}}

#to
e = {'b':{'ac':'no'}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With single dict comprehension:

```
e = {k:v for k, v in e.items() if v.items() != f.get(k, {}).items()}
```

---

```
{'b': {'ac': 'no'}}
```

---

[**dict.get(key[, default])**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) allows you to set the *needed*(or preferred) default value returned for the `key` in `dict`

Comment: While a good answer it's a terribly complex one-liner for someone who doesn't know they can't modify the length of what they're iterating. Black magic in that case, I think, and to be avoided.

Comment: @Vetsin, 1) I don't consider this as "terribly complex one-liner"; 2) I don't use "Black magic".

Comment: Nothing complex about this, thanks for sharing! I noticed my expected output was wrong, it should include at most 1 `a`, so essentially, remove duplicates. But this achieved it regardless.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not add or remove items from iterables that you are currently iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

As you've been told, you can't modify the length of a thing while you're iterating it. There are a few options here, such as:

Saving a list of what you want to remove, then doing it later:

```
to_remove = []
for keys, values in e.items():
    for k, v in f.items():
        if values.get('aa') == v.get('aa'):
            to_remove.append(keys)
            
for tr in to_remove:
    e.pop(tr)
```

Cloning the object, so that what you're iterating does not change but the original object can be modified. This is even more memory expensive than the previous however.

```
for keys, values in dict(e).items(): # or list(e.items())
    for k, v in f.items():
        if values.get('aa') == v.get('aa'):
            e.pop(keys)
```

You could also, in your case, simply create a new object:

```
g = {}
for keys, values in e.items():
    for k, v in f.items():
        if values.get('aa') != v.get('aa'):
            g[keys] = values
```